# how to avoid repeating last session php session_start();

Tags: php, session

I am using session to store products in cart in my site. But When I login with existing items in my cart then it will double the payment of last item which added in the cart. It is because of when I login then it will again start a session(which repeat the previous session). I don't know how to fix that.

in cart.php code

```
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['add'])) {

    $quantity = mysql_query('SELECT id, quantity FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['add']));

    while ($quantity_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quantity)) {
        if ($quantity_row['quantity']!=$_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]) {
            $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]+='1';
        }
    }

    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

}

`
init.php for login users
`
session_start();

require 'database/connect.php';

require 'functions/general.php';

require 'functions/users.php';

$current_file = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$current_file = end($current_file);

if (logged_in() === true) {
    $session_user_id= $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id,'user_id','username','password', 'first_name','last_name','email','type','allow_email', 'profile');
    if (user_active($user_data['username']) === false) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}

$errors=array();
```

Comment: I think it is not related with session problem, it may be having logic mistake...

Comment: Yes, But I dont know where I can find that problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to avoid repeating last session php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124695/how-to-avoid-repeating-last-session-php)

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) { //if there's no session_start yet...
    session_start(); //do this
}
else{
   //do other things...
}
```

**reference**:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

Comment: I think you should put that in place of your session_start();

Comment: and what I will put in place of  //do other things... ? in
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) { //if there's no session_start yet...
    session_start(); //do this
}
else{
   //do other things...
}